# Disbale Chrome Control in Client Webpart

Tags: 2013, web-part, sharepoint-addin

I have implemented an app which uses the SharePoint Chrome control to provide a better look and feel. This looks great when the app is opened fullscreen.
However, when the app is hosted in a client webpart inside my SharePoint sites, it looks ridiculous because the client webpart has its own chrome control.

I tried disabling it in the webpart settings, but it was ignored.

It is an SharePoint online autohosted app.

Has anyone a solution for how do deal with my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just set it to `display:none` via JavaScript. So I have all the CSS classes and the SharePoint look and feel but not the Chrome control.